# Why can I not see debug information for Boost::scoped_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, boost

I defined a scope pointer:

```
scoped_ptr<MyClass> ptr;
```

When I try to debug (using Visual Studio 2010), I cannot see debug information for `ptr`. Why?

Comment: Give us more info like type of application, debug/release mode are optimizations turned on?

Comment: on a shared_ptr you can see the object encapsulated, on scoped ptr theres notting to see on the watch window, its a simple question, I also would like to know